# How can I pretty-print XML source using VB6 and MSXML?

Tags: vb6, msxml, pretty-print

I've been looking after this for months now and I mostly found sites asking the same question.

The answers I *did* found were always for .NET or C++ or involved XSLT.

Comment: You can also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10202576/18771

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After months of research I've come up with this.

```
Public Function PrettyPrintXML(XML As String) As String

  Dim Reader As New SAXXMLReader60
  Dim Writer As New MXXMLWriter60

  Writer.indent = True
  Writer.standalone = False
  Writer.omitXMLDeclaration = False
  Writer.encoding = "utf-8"

  Set Reader.contentHandler = Writer
  Set Reader.dtdHandler = Writer
  Set Reader.errorHandler = Writer

  Call Reader.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", _
          Writer)
  Call Reader.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", _
          Writer)

  Call Reader.parse(XML)

  PrettyPrintXML = Writer.output

End Function
```

Using a document:

```
Public Function PrettyPrintDocument(Doc As DOMDocument60) As String
  PrettyPrintDocument = PrettyPrintXML(Doc.XML)
End Function
```

Comment: Very nice.  I've been looking for something this simple - that didn't require additional libraries or recursion - for a very long time.

Comment: Superb - thank you very much for taking the time to develop and post this.

Comment: How would you use it if the information is taken through a sql server query?

Comment: What reference do you use to use SAXXMLReader60

Comment: I need to create an xml file using vb6 using an sql query

Comment: The reference is `Microsoft XML, v6.0` from `msxml6.dll`