# How do I add whitespace/formatting to XML created in vbscript?

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm using vbscript to write form data to an XML file:

```
    Set objRecord = objDom.createElement("story")
    objRoot.appendChild objRecord


    Set objField = objDom.createElement("first")
    objField.Text = Request.Form("fName")
    objRecord.appendChild objField
```

which works, but the output has no formatting like you would expect from an XML file:

```
    <story><first>Jennifer</first></story><story><first>David</first></story><story><first>Austin</first></story><story><first>Steve</first></story>
```

I'm trying to achieve:

```
    <story>
        <first>Jennifer</first>
    </story>
    <story>
        <first>David</first>
    </story>
```

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oleg says](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000327.html) You can pretty print an *existing* XML file using Javascript this way:

```
  var reader = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.SAXXMLReader.4.0");
  var writer = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.MXXMLWriter.4.0");        
  writer.indent = true;
  writer.standalone = true;
  reader.contentHandler = writer;            
  reader.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", writer);
  reader.parseURL("source.xml");
```

That should be pretty easy to translate to VBScript.

Comment: not easy for me, but it led me to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118576/how-can-i-pretty-print-xml-source-using-vb6-and-msxml), which is exactly what I couldn't find in my searches. Thanks

Comment: You can run javascript on the server.
change your opening script tag to this :

<script language="JScript" runat="server">

and try running to see results