# How to Generate a well formatted XML file using VB 6.0?

Tags: xml, vb6

I'm working on Visual Basic 6.0 Project and i need to generate a well formatted XML file whose looks like this:

```
<Myinfo>
      <FirstName>My First Name</FirstName>
      <LastName>My Last Name</LastName>
      <StreetAdd>My Address</StreetAdd>
<MyInfo>
```

Note: i got the job done generating the XML file, but i'm still in need for the right formatting as shown above.

The XML file i generated is formatted like in one single line like this:

```
<Myinfo><FirstName>My First Name</FirstName><LastName>My Last Name</LastName><StreetAdd>My Address</StreetAdd><MyInfo> .
```

Comment: Your example XML files are identical as far as XML is concerned.

Comment: What does displaying as a tree have to do with the whitespace in your XML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print XML source using VB6 and MSXML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118576/how-can-i-pretty-print-xml-source-using-vb6-and-msxml)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  Where's any mention of MSXML in OP's question?    The answers to that question might be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a small XML pretty printer that works quite well:

```vb
Sub PrettyPrint(Parent As IXMLDOMNode, Optional Level As Integer)
  Dim Node As IXMLDOMNode
  Dim Indent As IXMLDOMText

  If Not Parent.ParentNode Is Nothing And Parent.ChildNodes.Length > 0 Then
    For Each Node In Parent.ChildNodes
      Set Indent = Node.OwnerDocument.createTextNode(vbNewLine & String(Level, vbTab))

      If Node.NodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
        If Trim(Node.Text) = "" Then
          Parent.RemoveChild Node
        End If
      ElseIf Node.PreviousSibling Is Nothing Then
        Parent.InsertBefore Indent, Node
      ElseIf Node.PreviousSibling.NodeType <> NODE_TEXT Then
        Parent.InsertBefore Indent, Node
      End If
    Next Node
  End If

  If Parent.ChildNodes.Length > 0 Then
    For Each Node In Parent.ChildNodes
      If Node.NodeType <> NODE_TEXT Then PrettyPrint Node, Level + 1
    Next Node
  End If
End Sub
```

You call it by passing in the `DOMDocument` object and leaving the `Level` parameter blank.

- It does an in-place modification of the document.
- You will lose all insignificant whitespace (blanks between XML elements) that might have been there.
- It uses one tab to indent.
- It also indents comments and processing instructions etc.
- it will work with all versions of `DOMDocument`.

```vb
Dim XmlDoc as New MSXML2.DOMDocument40

' create/load your xml document

PrettyPrint XmlDoc

MsgBox XmlDoc.xml
```

There also is an easy way to do it [via SAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118576/how-can-i-pretty-print-xml-source-using-vb6-and-msxml).

Answer (score 1):

You need to count the nesting of the tags, and output indentation corresponding to the depth of nesting.  Something like (forgive my bad VB6 syntax):

```
Int Nesting=0
Bool LastOutputWasText=false

Sub XMLIndent
   Do I=1,Nesting
     Print " ";
   End Do
End Sub

Sub XMLOutputOpenTag(String OpenTag)
    if LastOutputWasText then
      Print
    endif
    XMLIndent
    Nesting=Nesting+1
    Print OpenTag;
    LastOutputWasText=true
End Sub

Sub XMLOutputCloseTag(String CloseTag)
    ! Always call OpenTag and CloseTag with matching Tag names
    if !LastOutputWasText then
       XMLIndent
    endif
    Print CloseTag
    Nesting=Nesting-1
    LastOutputWasText=false
End Sub

Sub XMLOutputText(String Text)
    Print Text;
    LastOutputWasText=true
End Sub
```

OP left to revise this to write to a file or whereever he wants the result.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be using an XML library to create "correct" XML. It handles encoding, data formats, etc

```
Set XMLDoc = New DOMDocument
Set XMLRoot = XMLDoc.appendChild(XMLDoc.createElement("Myinfo"))
XMLRoot.appendChild(XMLDoc.createElement("FirstName")).Text = "My First Name"
XMLRoot.appendChild(XMLDoc.createElement("LastName")).Text = "My Last Name"
XMLRoot.appendChild(XMLDoc.createElement("StreetAdd")).Text = "My Address"
```

`XMLDoc.xml` will then output valid XML, or you can pretty print it as Tomalak suggests if you really want to.

Comment: Nitpicking: It will generate *well-formed* XML. Whether it is valid or not is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little improvement to Tomalak's code, I'm adding a vbNewLine after the end of the tag:

```
Private Sub FormatOuterXml(ByRef Parent As IXMLDOMNode, Optional ByVal Lvl As Long = 0)

    If Parent.ParentNode Is Nothing Or Parent.ChildNodes.Length = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim xn0 As IXMLDOMNode, id0 As IXMLDOMText, id1 As IXMLDOMText
    Set id0 = Parent.OwnerDocument.createTextNode(vbNewLine & String(Lvl, vbTab))

    If Lvl > 0 Then Set id1 = Parent.OwnerDocument.createTextNode(vbNewLine & String(Lvl - 1, vbTab))

    For Each xn0 In Parent.ChildNodes
        If xn0.NodeType = MSXML2.NODE_TEXT Then
            If LenB(xn0.Text) = 0 Then Parent.RemoveChild xn0
        ElseIf xn0.PreviousSibling Is Nothing Then
            Parent.InsertBefore id0.CloneNode(True), xn0
        ElseIf xn0.PreviousSibling.NodeType <> MSXML2.NODE_TEXT Then
            Parent.InsertBefore id0.CloneNode(True), xn0
        ElseIf xn0.NextSibling Is Nothing Then
            If Not id1 Is Nothing Then Parent.appendChild id1.CloneNode(True)
        End If
    Next xn0

    If Parent.ChildNodes.Length > 0 Then
        For Each xn0 In Parent.ChildNodes
            If xn0.NodeType <> MSXML2.NODE_TEXT Then FormatOuterXml xn0, Lvl + 1
       Next xn0
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: hey, it's a recursive function, not sure why it was called PrettyPrint2, I've changed the function name to FormatOuterXml