# Put attributes in the XML file using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, vba7, vba6

How do I put the attributes below that are in the node `envideclaracaoautodesembaraco` in my vba code. I want my `.xml` file to generate the same attributes as the example below.

```
<enviDeclaracaoAutodesembaraco 
      xmlns="http://www.sefaz.am.gov.br/autodesembaraco" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sefaz.am.gov.br/autodesembaraco enviDeclaracaoMensalAuto_v1.02.xsd">
   <infDeclaracaoMensal versao="01">
      <ieContribuinteDeclarante>063010712</ieContribuinteDeclarante>
      <anoApresentacao>2024</anoApresentacao>
      <mesApresentacao>01</mesApresentacao>
      <nomeResponsavel>RAI RODRIGUES</nomeResponsavel>
      <foneResponsavel>0000000000</foneResponsavel>
      <emailResponsavel>teste@gmail.com.br</emailResponsavel>`
      ...snip...
```

Image of attributes in the xml file:

[image]

Below my codes that exports an xml file in vba:

```
Sub xmlExport()

'On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    
    Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim root As IXMLDOMNode, ItemNode As IXMLDOMNode, yinstanceNode As IXMLDOMNode, UFNode As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim DiaAtributos As IXMLDOMAttribute, Atributos As IXMLDOMAttribute, NFatributos As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim Reconhecer As IXMLDOMElement, ValorBs As IXMLDOMElement, chave As IXMLDOMElement, NumNotas As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim NumItens As IXMLDOMElement, Produtos As IXMLDOMElement, NumItemNFe As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim CodInterno As IXMLDOMElement, IndGeral As IXMLDOMElement, IndGeralProdutos As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim TipoTributação As IXMLDOMElement, Multiplicador As IXMLDOMElement, ValorImposto As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim NumeroAtributo As IXMLDOMAttribute, civilityAttrib As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim IE As IXMLDOMElement, Ano As IXMLDOMElement, Mes As IXMLDOMElement, Nome As IXMLDOMElement, Fone As IXMLDOMElement, Email As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim ListaNF As IXMLDOMElement, NF As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim nmsp As String
    Dim g As Long

    
    ' NODE PAI '
    nmsp = "http://www.sefaz.am.gov.br/autodesembaraco"
    Set root = doc.createElement("enviDeclaracaoAutodesembaraco")
    doc.appendChild root
    
    Set DiaAtributos = doc.createAttribute("xsischemaLocation")
    DiaAtributos.Value = "http://www.sefaz.am.gov.br/autodesembaraco enviDeclaracaoMensalAuto_v1.02.xsd"
    root.Attributes.setNamedItem DiaAtributos
    
    Set ItemNode = doc.createElement("infDeclaracaoMensal")
    root.appendChild ItemNode
    
    Set Atributos = doc.createAttribute("versao")
    Atributos.Value = "01"
    ItemNode.Attributes.setNamedItem Atributos
    
    Set IE = doc.createElement("ieContribuinteDeclarante")
    IE.Text = Range("b2").Value
    ItemNode.appendChild IE

    Set Ano = doc.createElement("anoApresentacao")
    Ano.Text = Range("c2").Value
    ItemNode.appendChild Ano

    Set Mes = doc.createElement("mesApresentacao")
    Mes.Text = Range("d2").Value
    ItemNode.appendChild Mes
    
    Set Nome = doc.createElement("nomeResponsavel")
    Nome.Text = Range("e2").Value
    ItemNode.appendChild Nome

    Set Fone = doc.createElement("foneResponsavel")
    Fone.Text = Range("f2").Value
    ItemNode.appendChild Fone
    
    Set Email = doc.createElement("emailResponsavel")
    Email.Text = Range("g2").Value
    ItemNode.appendChild Email
    
    Set ListaNF = doc.createElement("listaNotasFiscais")
    ItemNode.appendChild ListaNF
    
     
    
 For g = 2 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
 
    NumeroItemNfe = Cells(g, 15)
 
 If NumeroItemNfe = 1 Then
    
    Set NF = doc.createElement("notaFiscal")
    ListaNF.appendChild NF
    
    Set NFatributos = doc.createAttribute("numOrdemNota")
    NFatributos.Value = Range("h" & g)
    NF.setAttributeNode NFatributos
    
    Set chave = doc.createElement("chaveNFe")
    chave.Text = Range("j" & g)
    NF.appendChild chave
    
    Set Reconhecer = doc.createElement("reconheceNFe")
    Reconhecer.Text = Range("L" & g)
    NF.appendChild Reconhecer
    
    Set NumItens = doc.createElement("numItens")
    NumItens.Text = Range("M" & g)
    NF.appendChild NumItens
    
    'Else
    
    'GoTo ProximaInteracao
    
    End If
    
'ProximaInteracao:

    Set Produtos = doc.createElement("produto")
    NF.appendChild Produtos

    Set NumItemNFe = doc.createElement("numItemNFe")
    NumItemNFe.Text = Range("O" & g)
    Produtos.appendChild NumItemNFe

    Set CodInterno = doc.createElement("codInternoProduto")
    CodInterno.Text = Range("P" & g)
    Produtos.appendChild CodInterno

    Set IndGeral = doc.createElement("indiceCodGeralProduto")
    IndGeral.Text = Range("Q" & g)
    Produtos.appendChild IndGeral

    Set IndGeralProdutos = doc.createElement("codGeralProduto")
    IndGeralProdutos.Text = Range("R" & g)
    Produtos.appendChild IndGeralProdutos
    
    Set TipoTributação = doc.createElement("codTipoTributacao")
    TipoTributação.Text = Range("S" & g)
    Produtos.appendChild TipoTributação
    
    Set ValorBs = doc.createElement("valorBaseCalculoItem")
    ValorBs.Text = Replace(Format(Range("T" & g), "0.00"), ",", ".")
    Produtos.appendChild ValorBs
    
    Set Multiplicador = doc.createElement("valorMultiplicador")
    Multiplicador.Text = Replace(Format(Range("U" & g), "0.00"), ",", ".")
    Produtos.appendChild Multiplicador
    
    Set ValorImposto = doc.createElement("valorImpostoDeclarado")
    ValorImposto.Text = Replace(Format(Range("V" & g), "0.00"), ",", ".")
    Produtos.appendChild ValorImposto
    
Next g

    Set NumNotas = doc.createElement("numNotasArquivo")
    NumNotas.Text = Range("W2").Value
    ItemNode.appendChild NumNotas

    
    xslDoc.LoadXML "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?>" _
            & "<xsl:stylesheet version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) _
            & "                xmlns:xsl=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" & Chr(34) & ">" _
            & "<xsl:strip-space elements=" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
            & "<xsl:output method=" & Chr(34) & "xml" & Chr(34) & " indent=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "" _
            & "            encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "/>" _
            & " <xsl:template match=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & ">" _
            & "  <xsl:copy>" _
            & "   <xsl:apply-templates select=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
            & "  </xsl:copy>" _
            & " </xsl:template>" _
            & "</xsl:stylesheet>"
            

            
    xslDoc.async = False
    doc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save baseDirectory & projectName & "C:\Users\raI\Downloads\DIA.xml"
    
    

    MsgBox "Arquivo XML gerado com sucesso!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

'ErrHandle:
    'MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

The above codes in visual basic for application export an excel data xml file.

How did the xml file look after changing the code as per the suggestion.

```
<enviDeclaracaoAutodesembaraco xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sefaz.am.gov.br/autodesembaraco" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sefaz.am.gov.br/autodesembaraco enviDeclaracaoMensalAuto_v1.02.xsd">
  <infDeclaracaoMensal xmlns="" versao="01">
```

Comment: You should **avoid** writing your whole question in **ALL CAPS** - this is generally considered **SHOUTING** at your audience, it's rude and offensive, and dramatically lowers your chances of folks taking their time to read your question and provide an answer. Don't do it - just don't .

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm new here, I'm still getting the hang of how to use the platform.

Comment: FYI creating a lot of XML elements step-by-step can end up quite repetitive: consider one or two utility methods to handle the repetitive parts in one call.  Eg see `CreateWithAttributes` here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70089478/478884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issues i think you're having are adding the attributs to the root element:

- `xmlns="http://www.sefaz.am.gov.br/autodesembaraco"`
- `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`
- `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sefaz.am.gov.br/autodesembaraco enviDeclaracaoMensalAuto_v1.02.xsd"`

The issue was with how you're creating the namespaces schema location:

```
Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim root As IXMLDOMNode
Dim nmsp As String, xsi As String, schemaLocation As String

' namespaces and schema location
nmsp = "http://www.sefaz.am.gov.br/autodesembaraco"
xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
schemaLocation = "http://www.sefaz.am.gov.br/autodesembaraco enviDeclaracaoMensalAuto_v1.02.xsd"
```

1. Create the root element by passing the namespace:

```
' Create the root element - with namespace - by using createNode (NODE_ELEMENT = 1)
Set root = doc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "enviDeclaracaoAutodesembaraco", nmsp)
doc.appendChild root
```

2. Declare the `xsi` namespace:

```
' Add xmlns:xsi attribute
Set xsiAttr = doc.createAttribute("xmlns:xsi")
xsiAttr.Value = xsi
root.Attributes.setNamedItem xsiAttr
```

3. Add the `schemaLocation`:

```
' Add xsi:schemaLocation attribute
Set schemaLocationAttr = doc.createAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation")
schemaLocationAttr.Value = schemaLocation
```

Comment: Hi Ian, how are you? Thank you very much for your help, I did as you suggested, the attributes appeared, but the "xmlns:xsi" attribute is appearing in front of the "xmlns" attribute, can I convert this?

Another question, in the "infDeclaraçãoMonsal" node, the "xmlns" attribute is appearing behind the "version: 01" attribute, is there any way I can remove this xmlns attribute from this Node?

I'll answer my own question by explaining how it turned out.

Comment: @RaíRodrigues Can you show the XML you're now getting - not all of it; just the root element and its attributes.

Comment: Second issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220095/remove-unwanted-empty-xmlns-attribute-added-by-appendchild/13229110#13229110

Comment: @IanBoyd I placed the requested information at the end of my question.