Creating XML file using Excel VBA
I' trying to create xml file from Excel VBA to my work.
Issues I am facing are following.

I have spend a days trying to add the structure !-- elementx -- after each element.
Also I am not able to get preatty formating.

Belowe you will find my VBA code ( these are myfisrt steps with xml and VBA)
I appreciate your help with this.
Public Sub ExportXMLfile()
Dim doc As Object
Dim Root As Object
Dim pi As Object
Dim Spath As String
Dim Cdata As Object

Dim Product As Object
Dim Element1 As Object
Dim Element2 As Object
Dim Element3 As Object

Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set pi = doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", " version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""")
doc.appendChild pi

Set Root = doc.createElement("Document")
doc.appendChild Root
Root.setAttribute "generated", Now
Root.appendChild doc.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)


Set Root = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Document")

For i = 1 To 3
    
    Set Product = doc.createElement("Product")
    Root.appendChild Product
    Product.appendChild doc.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab + vbTab)
    
    
    Set Element1 = doc.createElement("Element1")
    Product.appendChild Element1
    Set Cdata = doc.createCDATASection("Element1")
    Cdata.Data = i
    Element1.appendChild Cdata
    
    
    
    Set Element2 = doc.createElement("Element2")
    Element2.text = i
    Product.appendChild Element2
    
    
    Set Element3 = doc.createElement("Element3")
    Element3.text = i
    Product.appendChild Element3
    
    Product.appendChild doc.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
Next

Root.appendChild doc.createTextNode(vbNewLine)

Debug.Print doc.XML


End Sub

With my code I get the following output so far.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document generated="11/11/2024 10:24:33 AM">
    <Product>
        <Element1><![CDATA[1]]></Element1><Element2>1</Element2><Element3>1</Element3>
    </Product><Product>
        <Element1><![CDATA[2]]></Element1><Element2>2</Element2><Element3>2</Element3>
    </Product><Product>
        <Element1><![CDATA[3]]></Element1><Element2>3</Element2><Element3>3</Element3>
    </Product>
</Document>

The output should actually look like this.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document generated="11/11/2024 10:24:33 AM">
    <Product>
        <Element1><![CDATA[1]]></Element1><!-- element1 -->
        <Element2>1</Element2><!-- element2 -->
        <Element3>1</Element3><!-- element3 -->
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Element1><![CDATA[2]]></Element1><!-- element1 -->
        <Element2>2</Element2><!-- element2 -->
        <Element3>2</Element3><!-- element3 -->
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Element1><![CDATA[3]]></Element1><!-- element1 -->
        <Element2>3</Element2><!-- element2 -->
        <Element3>3</Element3><!-- element3 -->
    </Product>
</Document>


What do you really try accomplishing? Besides playing with xml...

I am trying to write the vba code which convert my data from excel table to xml file. The excel file will be shared and manipulated by the team. The code will be automatically transform the data form the excel to xml.

You may check the revised code which includes adding comments and prettify output to a text file as well as immediate window.

One more question to full understand. When I change the parameter xmlWriter.omitXMLDeclaration to False I get an information that encoding is UTF-16 not UTF-8. How can I get UTF-8 ?

I just added a new answer which solves the encoding problem in the created text file.

This works for me as per your expected output where the generated XML file (Test.xml) will be created in the folder which houses the Excel file.

Revision-1: Adding comments in the XML table
Revision-2: Prettify output of the XML table

Sub Test()
    Dim objConn As Object, strArgs As String, strSQL As String, i As Integer
    Dim xDoc As Object, objRoot As Object, myNode As Object, Cdata As Object, newComment As Object
    Dim ChildNode As Variant, New_ChildNode As Variant
    Dim XML_FileName As String, tempFileName As String
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFile As Object, strXML As String, xmlWriter As Object, strOutput As String, objTextFile As Object
    
    Const ForReading = 1
    
    Set xmlWriter = CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter")

    Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xDoc.async = False
    xDoc.validateOnParse = False
    xDoc.resolveExternals = True
    
    Set objRoot = xDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")
    Set objRoot = xDoc.InsertBefore(objRoot, xDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0))
    Set objRoot = xDoc.createElement("Document")
    Set xDoc.DocumentElement = objRoot
    
    objRoot.setAttribute "generated", Now
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        Set myNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Document")
        
        Set ChildNode = xDoc.createElement("Product")
        myNode.appendChild ChildNode
        
        Set New_ChildNode = xDoc.createElement("Element1")
        ChildNode.appendChild New_ChildNode
        Set Cdata = xDoc.createCDATASection("Element1")
        Cdata.Data = i
        New_ChildNode.appendChild Cdata
        
        Set newComment = xDoc.CreateComment("My comment for Element1")
        ChildNode.appendChild newComment
        
        Set New_ChildNode = xDoc.createElement("Element2")
        New_ChildNode.Text = i
        ChildNode.appendChild New_ChildNode
        
        Set newComment = xDoc.CreateComment("My comment for Element2")
        ChildNode.appendChild newComment
        
        Set New_ChildNode = xDoc.createElement("Element3")
        New_ChildNode.Text = i
        ChildNode.appendChild New_ChildNode
        
        Set newComment = xDoc.CreateComment("My comment for Element3")
        ChildNode.appendChild newComment
    Next
    
    tempFileName = "Test"
    XML_FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & tempFileName & ".xml"
    xDoc.Save XML_FileName
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(XML_FileName, ForReading)
    strXML = objFile.readall
    
    Set xmlWriter = CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter")
    xmlWriter.omitXMLDeclaration = True
    xmlWriter.indent = True
    xmlWriter.Encoding = "utf-8"
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader")
        Set .contentHandler = xmlWriter
        .putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", xmlWriter
        .Parse strXML
    End With
    
    strOutput = xmlWriter.output
    Debug.Print strOutput
    
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "myXML.txt")
    objTextFile.WriteLine strOutput
    objTextFile.Close
    
    Set objTextFile = Nothing
    Set xmlWriter = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set myNode = Nothing
    Set New_ChildNode = Nothing
    Set ChildNode = Nothing
    Set objRoot = Nothing
    Set xDoc = Nothing
End Sub

.
Note: You may use xmlWriter.omitXMLDeclaration = False to add the XML declaration in top of the body created in the text file.
.
Screenshot of the XML file:

.
Screenshot of the text file:


Please use either myNode.appendChild ChildNode or Call myNode.appendChild(ChildNode)

@FunThomas ... done!

there is needed  a text  after each element. how to add it ?

The text you mentioned is actually a comment. I revised my code which includes adding comments in the XML table. The screenshot of the output is also added

Thank you for your help Haluk this is what I had try to achieve. The last thing if I could ask is formatting. When I open the file by notepad there is one line. I have found a solution how I can format and debugprint but there isn't an information how save results to the file. Is there any chance to support ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118576/how-can-i-pretty-print-xml-source-using-vb6-and-msxml#new-answer

Check the revision in the post. Now, comments are added and prettify output to the immediate window is added and a text file is also created with the XML file. The text file and XML file will be created in the folder housing the Excel file. If your problem is solved please accept my post as an Answer.

I continued working on the problem for getting the correct encoding as UTF-8 in the text file, and finally created the below procedure and the function.
Copy the below procedure Test2 and the function ParseAndSave, paste them in a standard code module and run the procedure Test2.
Test.xml and Test.txt will be created in the folder which houses the Excel file. The XML output will be displayed in the immediate window as well.
Note: Coded and tested on Excel 2010 (64 Bit)
Screenshot of the file Test.txt is also given below.
Sub Test2()
    Dim objConn As Object, strArgs As String, strSQL As String, i As Integer
    Dim xDoc As Object, objRoot As Object, myNode As Object, Cdata As Object, newComment As Object
    Dim ChildNode As Variant, New_ChildNode As Variant
    Dim XML_FileName As String, tempFileName As String, Text_FileName As String
        
    Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xDoc.async = False
    xDoc.validateOnParse = False
    xDoc.resolveExternals = True
    
    Set objRoot = xDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'")
    Set objRoot = xDoc.InsertBefore(objRoot, xDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0))
    Set objRoot = xDoc.createElement("Document")
    Set xDoc.DocumentElement = objRoot
    
    objRoot.setAttribute "generated", Now
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        Set myNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Document")
        
        Set ChildNode = xDoc.createElement("Product")
        myNode.appendChild ChildNode
        
        Set New_ChildNode = xDoc.createElement("Element1")
        ChildNode.appendChild New_ChildNode
        Set Cdata = xDoc.createCDATASection("Element1")
        Cdata.Data = i
        New_ChildNode.appendChild Cdata
        
        Set newComment = xDoc.CreateComment("My comment for Element1")
        ChildNode.appendChild newComment
        
        Set New_ChildNode = xDoc.createElement("Element2")
        New_ChildNode.Text = i
        ChildNode.appendChild New_ChildNode
        
        Set newComment = xDoc.CreateComment("My comment for Element2")
        ChildNode.appendChild newComment
        
        Set New_ChildNode = xDoc.createElement("Element3")
        New_ChildNode.Text = i
        ChildNode.appendChild New_ChildNode
        
        Set newComment = xDoc.CreateComment("My comment for Element3")
        ChildNode.appendChild newComment
    Next
    
'   Write data to XML file
    tempFileName = "Test"
    XML_FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & tempFileName & ".xml"
    xDoc.Save XML_FileName
    
'   Write data to text file
    tempFileName = "Test"
    Text_FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & tempFileName & ".txt"
        
    Call ParseAndSave(Text_FileName, xDoc)
    
'   Clean-up
    Set myNode = Nothing
    Set New_ChildNode = Nothing
    Set ChildNode = Nothing
    Set objRoot = Nothing
    Set xDoc = Nothing
End Sub
'
Function ParseAndSave(filePath, xmlDoc)
    Dim xmlWriter As Object, xmlReader As Object, xmlStream As Object
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFile As Object, strXML As String
    
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    Const ForReading = 1

    Set xmlWriter = CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter")
    Set xmlReader = CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader")
    
    Set xmlStream = CreateObject("ADODB.STREAM")
    xmlStream.Open
    xmlStream.Charset = "UTF-8"

    xmlWriter.output = xmlStream
    xmlWriter.indent = True
    xmlWriter.standalone = True
    xmlWriter.byteOrderMark = True
    xmlWriter.Encoding = "UTF-8"
    xmlWriter.omitXMLDeclaration = False

    Set xmlReader.contentHandler = xmlWriter
    Set xmlReader.DTDHandler = xmlWriter
    Set xmlReader.errorHandler = xmlWriter
    xmlReader.putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", xmlWriter
    xmlReader.putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", xmlWriter

    xmlReader.Parse xmlDoc
    xmlWriter.flush

    xmlStream.SaveToFile filePath, adSaveCreateOverWrite

    xmlStream.Close
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading)
    strXML = objFile.readall
    
'   Write data to immediate window
    Debug.Print Mid(strXML, 4, Len(strXML) - 3)
    
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set xmlStream = Nothing
    Set xmlWriter = Nothing
    Set xmlReader = Nothing
End Function

Screenshot of the text file:


Appreciate your addition how to stay with utf-8 encoding when negating to omit the xml declaration by xmlWriter.omitXMLDeclaration = False +:) - Btw Why don't you bind to version 6.0, i.e. via CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader.6.0") and CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter.6.0") and of course CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0") ?

@T.M. sure 6.0 can be used also. But as you know; omitting the version, VBA will be forced to use the latest version available. As long as you are not using a new method or feature in the XX.0 version it is more safe to use the basic version. This is my opinion... On the other hand, omitXMLDeclaration is False by default, but anyway I added it in the code explicitly.
